# .NET Core API JwtBearerEvents.TokenValidated - race condition between multiple API requests

Tags: .net, .net-core, oauth-2.0, jwt

I'm overriding `JwtBearerEvents.TokenValidated` in order to match a User in my database against the Authenticated User (from a 3rd party authentication service - via JWT), and then populating some custom claims for me to use within my API (user subscription level, for example).

This code is tiggered from the `Startup.cs`, and is called for every API request. Within `TokenValidated`, I try to load the user associated with the token, and if they don't exist I create a User in the database.

However, I have the scenario that a client will make multiple requests against my API, and if this is a user that does not yet exist, the API creates multiple users - one for each time `TokenValidated` is called in parallel.

The code:

```
public class CustomJwtBearerEvents : JwtBearerEvents
{
    private IUsersRepository _usersRepository;

    public CustomJwtBearerEvents(IUsersRepository usersRepository)
    {
        this._usersRepository = usersRepository;
    }

    public override async Task TokenValidated(TokenValidatedContext context)
    {
        var subject = context.Principal.FindFirstValue("user_id");

        var dbUser = await _usersRepository.GetOrCreateUser(subject, context.Principal);

        // Populate custom claims
    }
}
```

I'm sure that I'm approaching this wrong, but I'm not sure how best to solve this problem - so this is my question:

How should I match 3rd Party authentication users to users in my database, whilst allowing concurrent API requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could approach this. The most straight forward might be to implement a `lock` around the portion of the code that calls `_usersRepository.GetOrCreateUser(subject, context.Principal);` That would ensure only one thread at a time could access that line of code, preventing any dirty reads & duplicate inserts.

That code would look something like this

```
public class CustomJwtBearerEvents : JwtBearerEvents
{
    private readonly object _key = new object();
    private IUsersRepository _usersRepository;

    public CustomJwtBearerEvents(IUsersRepository usersRepository)
    {
        this._usersRepository = usersRepository;
    }

    public override async Task TokenValidated(TokenValidatedContext context)
    {
        var subject = context.Principal.FindFirstValue("user_id");

        lock(_key)
        {
            var dbUser = await _usersRepository.GetOrCreateUser(subject, context.Principal);
        }

        // Populate custom claims
    }
}
```

As you might guess, this isn't going be the most performant, effectively making each of your API calls wait for all other calls to finish.

To optimize a little bit, you might consider adding a `GetUser()` method to your `IUsersRepository` that can be used outside of the `lock`ed portion of the code.

This would allow any requests for users that already exist to execute without waiting & only locking the code when a new user must be created.

```
public class CustomJwtBearerEvents : JwtBearerEvents
{
    private readonly object _key = new object();
    private IUsersRepository _usersRepository;

    public CustomJwtBearerEvents(IUsersRepository usersRepository)
    {
        this._usersRepository = usersRepository;
    }

    public override async Task TokenValidated(TokenValidatedContext context)
    {
        var subject = context.Principal.FindFirstValue("user_id");

        var dbUser = await _usersRepository.GetUser(subject, context.Principal);

        if (dbUser is null) 
        {
            lock(_key)
            {
                dbUser = await _usersRepository.GetOrCreateUser(subject, context.Principal);
            }
        }

        // Populate custom claims
    }
}
```

---

All that said, the Microsoft.AspNet.Identity framework does a pretty good job of managing external user accounts, if that is something you are interested in checking out.

[Here is a link to their docs on the subject.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/additional-claims?view=aspnetcore-3.1)